# How do I store an image url coming from Flutter Image Picker in the Database for later use

Tags: ios, flutter

I have setup the code according to Flutter Image Picker documentation.

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

The method seen below does exactly as it should and it retrieves a url to the image selected from the picker.

```
Future handleEditProfilePic() async {
  final XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    maxWidth: 300,
    maxHeight: 300,
    imageQuality: 50,
  );

  setState(() {
    _image = image;
  });
}
```

Here is a sample of the type of url it returns:

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7021FEB0-EE3A-48CE-8E77-3F2A5D32867C/tmp/image_picker_B8C28D76-F5E7-48B7-B280-05013590CAC8-9304-0000102466C56AE8.jpg
```

After getting the url I am able to render the image properly. The code that renders the image is seen below.

```
Image.file(File(_image!),fit: BoxFit.cover);
```

Everything is good so far. Next I send the url to the database. Later after closing the application, reopening it and retrieving the url from the database attempting to use it, it fails.

I am guessing the url generated by the Image Picker is only existing within the lifecycle of the app and once closed it is no longer a valid url. I am guessing this only the url seem to be have a tmp segment possibly indicating temp storage.

I have looked at the documentation and have searched the internet looking at one tutorial after another trying to figure out what I am missing. Most all the tutorials are either showing instructions from older versions of the picker or they don't show anything about storing urls and getting the image later using the url.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Next I send the url to the database." Is this a local database or remote database? 
If local, try saving the image in pour apps directory.

Comment: It is a remote. I only used it because I read somewhere to save the url to the db and not the image and just use the url to get the image

Comment: What is "pour apps directory"?

Comment: Sorry meant your apps directory (This is not permanent).  Well you need to upload the image to a storage service like S3, firebase storage and store the link to your db.

Comment: So there's no way to use a dedicated path to the actual image in the device?

Answer (score 0):

Mabey you can solve this issue, follow bellow steps,

1.First you should add this package and import your place for pick image,

```
flutter pub add file_picker
```

you can refer more detail by using this [link](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker/versions/5.5.0/install).

2.You can pick image file bellow code segment,

```
 Future<void> pickFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result =
        await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);

    File imageFile = File(result?.files.single.path ?? "");
    String imageUrl = await uploadFile(imageFile); // Save image resources server it can be change your requirement
    print('On pick file method - $imageUrl');
    if (imageUrl.isNotEmpty) {
      print('Done');
      setState(() {
        widget.urlOfProfilePicture = imageUrl;
        updateDatabase(); // for store your image in databse for later use
      });
    }
  }
```

You can store your image in resourse server,

```
For upload image into resourse server,
     Future<String> uploadFile(File file) async {
        Dio dio = Dio();
    
        String imageURl;
    
        String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
        String filePath = file.path;
    
        FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
          'key': '6cf6fa29f38c1ea100e41ab748ff3cf4',
          'image': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: fileName)
        });
    
        var response = await dio.post(
          'https://example.com',
          data: formData,
          onSendProgress: (count, total) {
            print('$count, $total');
          },
        );
    
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final Map<String, dynamic> responseData = response.data;
          print('+++++++++Image Url+++++++++++');
          print(responseData['data']['display_url']);
          imageURl = responseData['data']['display_url'];
          updateSharedPreference(imageURl);
          return imageURl;
        }
        return '';
      }
```

now you can store your image url in database ,
You can use bellow code for Update databse, im using mysaql databse as a datase and I use nodejs as backend

```
 Future<void> updateDatabase() async {
    final requestURL = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/user/imageUrl');

    Map<String, dynamic> requestData = {
      "url": widget.urlOfProfilePicture,
      "User_id": userId
    };

    final response = await http.put(
      requestURL,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: jsonEncode(requestData),
    );
  }
```

Future updateDatabase() async {
final requestURL = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/user/imageUrl'); //this is url of my nodejs backend for store image url in databse

```
Map<String, dynamic> requestData = {
  "url": widget.urlOfProfilePicture,
  "User_id": userId
};

final response = await http.put(
  requestURL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  body: jsonEncode(requestData),
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  initData();
}}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid storing the image on another server since the application doesn't have that kind of user base. I actually just stored the profile pic in sqflite and left it all internal. Maybe at some point later this solution will be needed. Thanks.